# what's audio type of audio_common msg

Tags: ros, audio-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

on android,I want to receive and play audio recorded on ros, but I don't know stream type of the audio, is it mp3 or PWM, and what's sample rate and bit rate, confused ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58815/what%27s-audio-type-of-audio_common-msg/) by [maoqizhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4434/maoqizhen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While the message itself doesn't have any requirements, if you want the audio_play or audio_record nodes to work, all data should be mp3 (and specifically 192kbit/s).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1